# BlackBerry - How can i navigate to other Screen by clicking on a String in J2me or Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can i navigate to other Screen by clicking on a String in J2me or Blackberry ?
Please help me in this point.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can register a pattern with the BB OS, and have your application as an option when a match is found. Use the [PatternRepository](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/stringpattern/PatternRepository.html) to register either an exact match or a regular expression, and pass an [ApplicationDescriptor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationDescriptor.html). Like with URL's the matched string will be highlighted when the user scroll on it, and your application will be one of the optional menu items.

`PatternRepository.addPattern(ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(), myPattern, PatternRepository.PATTERN_TYPE_EXACT_MATCH, menuItemArray);`

Note: There's a problem with HTML formatted emails and the pattern may not be matched, only in plain text. RIM are aware of this problem and it should be fixed in the next release (one after 5.0)